# orientation issue in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, orientation

I have strange issue, my app is in landscape mode. its working fine in the iOS 8, but when it comes to iOS 7, 1st screen of app goes in portrait mode. If I push to other viewController and go back to 1st vc,then it goes in Landscape mode which i wanted

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the value of the frame when the 1st screen gets initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered an issue about orientations... and that was in iPhone.

And I remembered when running my app, the default orientation is Portrait when what I want is to default my app in Landscape mode. So I put the code below and it fixed my problem.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

**shouldAutorotate** returns YES because I wanted it to rotate in Landscape at first run.

Hope the story helps you, goodluck.